# Button continuously shows pressed status and can't display the result

Tags: java, events, jbutton

Below is my action class,the program can run, but sometimes when you pressed the button, it continuously shows pressed status,and the result can't display in the `JTextField`?

```
    public class SsqAction implements ActionListener{

    String luckNum="";
    private JTextField luckField;

    public SsqAction(JTextField luckField){
        this.luckField=luckField;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        int[] a={0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int tag=0;

        for(int k=0;k<6;){

            double i=Math.random()*33;
            int temp=(int)Math.ceil(i);
            a[k]=temp;
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
                if(a[j]==a[k]){
                    tag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(tag==0){
                k++;
            }

        }

        double j=Math.random()*16;
        int b=(int)Math.ceil(j);
        a[6]=b;

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            luckNum=luckNum+a[i]+" ";
        }

        luckField.setText(luckNum);

    }

}
```

Comment: The code you posted could not cause the problem you are describing. Please post an SSCCE, or just the rest of your code.

Comment: You probably have an infinite loop (`for(int k=0;k<6;)`) . Add traces to your code, debug it, or analyza it carefully to check when it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for loop

```
for(int k=0;k<6;)
```

You don't increment `k`. You increment it here:

```
if(tag==0){
   k++;
}
```

But, `tag` might be set to `1` here:

```
if(a[j]==a[k]){
   tag=1;
   break;
}
```

(`break` breaks the inner loop, not the external one)
Now, `tag` is `1` forever, and `k` will never be incremented → Infinite loop.

Tip: Use a debugger, he's your best friend.

Comment: Thank you @Maroun,I correted my programm with your answer.I put the assignment statement    'int tag=1' in the top loop,it works.Thank you！